# exe saves file ok, except when launched via Excel macro

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, .net-assembly, vba

I am new here

I have a c# program with WPF that

- generates some pdf
- saves it in the same directory
- then opens the pdf for viewing

-->all that works fine with no error when exe launched directly.

But when the .exe is lauched by an excel macro (shell function) in an excel file in the same directory: excel macro is OK,  program starts OK, generates the pdf OK, ... pdf is opened & viewed automatically OK (so makes me think the pdf was saved someghere)... and when all is closed ... not pdf in the directory !

It's probably an obvious general error, but I can't figure it out.
Detailed help appreciated as I am new to that
Fabrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel is using a different working directory, the file will be placed there and not where you expected.  If this is the case, you can use the following method...

```
    public string GetFullSaveName(string pdfName)
    {
        string myDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (myDirectoryName != null)
        {
            string fullSaveName = Path.Combine(myDirectoryName, pdfName);
            return fullSaveName;
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Unable to locate assembly path");
    }
```

This method uses Reflection to find out which directory your application is running in.  It uses this to build up a fully qualified path so that your pdf file will be written to a predictable place.  The path returned is the working directory of the *application*, and not Excel's.